# Are WordPress & PHP objectively and based on evidence going to die because the future is made of frontend rendering instead of server side rendering?

Tags: php

A friend called Pablo told me to learn WordPress CMS but another friend called Lucas told me to learn Strapi CMS because server side rendering and PHP in general are dying in favor of frontend side rendering with tools like react, angular or vue.

**I do not want your opinion** because opinions are strictly forbidden on this platform and they will make moderators close this question.

I want facts and solid arguments based on true evidence that demonstrate wether WordPress and server side rendering via PHP are really being replaced by the new javascript toys or not in the following 30 years (to be practical, because I will stop working on 2050 if I am still alive).

I really like PHP and cannot imagine a world without it.

But if you know better than me the objective factual non-opinionated tendency of web development and can help me take the smartest decision, I will be very happy today.

Comment: Well if Lucas says so...

Comment: Don't know why the names of your friends were relevant, but ok. You don't want opinions but you ask an opinion based question, we are not oracles, we can see the future to tell you exactly what would happen with PHP, react etc... . For now wordpress is still going strong, check for your self, and react/angular are also doing great. You want solid arguments... this is a QA site not a debate form.

Comment: @Jacob Peattie At least he says something.

Comment: You can't get anything but an opinion, because nobody knows the future. In any case, you need some code to store data on the server. Frontend code alone can't do that.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to answer this question using facts without waiting 30 years to see what happens, clairvoyance is required to answer this question, and it's unclear what an answer would look like without it being speculative. This is a discussion subject not a question, any response would be an opinion. Remember, this is not a forum

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do not worry about the future of PHP, it's here to stay. It powers more than 75% of websites as of 2021. The frontend rendering frameworks and libraries keep changing and most of them end up being passing fads, although it will be vital to learn those that are being used extensively e.g. React, Vue, Angular etc.

Here's a [link](https://www.zend.com/blog/state-php-2021) from Zend that delves deeper into the future of PHP.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer!

Comment: facts are that when I search for jobs node phyton and even java are in more demand than PHP. Zend do not exists realy any more and do not have much to say about the future of PHP in any case, the future of PHP depends on the core contributors to it and at least to the best of my knowledge there is no one entity which "owns" it and can answer anything about any future

Comment: @Mark Kaplun, so why did you create your own wordpress fork if you don't believe in PHPs future?

Comment: @MarkKaplun, a sound opinion about PHP doesn't have to come from the core contributors only but from any PHP enthusiast. Besides, PHP creators have worked so hard to come up with PHP 8 with some major updates that focus on PHP performance and make web development smoother and simpler. There are problems that PHP solves better than Java and Python and vice versa. Job postings from other coding languages does not devalue the use of PHP. As far web dev is concerned PHP wins hands down in terms of accessibility, ease-of-use and extensive community.

Comment: @Rodgath the OP asked for facts not opinions. For something to be a fact you need to see some documentation for it unless you have some intimate knowledge. Right now the only known fact about PHP is that there is very likely going to be 8.1. The article you linked to was by a former employee of zend or at least the compny that bought the relevant PHP IP from zend. His termination and the disbanding of his team came with an advanced notice of a month IIRC.

Comment: Right now nikic popov (I am probably mispelling) is the most prolific contributor for PHP. If he will switch his job (or maybe just marry a very rich girl/guy) there might be a 8.2 but it might take more time or have less features. In addition a lot of the popularity of PHP comes from it being installed by default on shared servers. If hosting companies will change their opinion about it, it will hurt its popularity more than anything else.

Comment: And just because WordPress is written in PHP do not mean much as for years the Matt wants to have most development to be done in JS in which case the old php used right now in core will be good enough and there will not be much PHP development needed even in WP

Comment: @MarkKaplun in the end PHP is a tool to talk with databases and process information. You can reinvent the wheel as much as you want but in the end whatever you use will spit out plain HTML/CSS. You can use as much frontend as you like for displaying stuff but the big brain that PHP is, you cannot say it will die. It's too beautiful to die. And yeah all this react, angular blablah is changing its form every day, it's exhausting. A new face every few weeks... yeah sure you can throw in some JS cherries to make your web more fluid or smooth, but there has to be a brain behind it all. And its PHP.

Comment: @Rodgath has been the clearest person so far. Your strange rules for this moderation system are weird. A question is a question after all.

Comment: @JavierGuilBozal, I admit the question is quite interesting and as you could see, it attracted various *opinions* which is why the question was closed. And I just wanted to respond to you on 2 things you said: 1) "And its PHP." - but not just PHP, right? 2) "A question is a question after all." - yes, but [a rule is also a rule](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and a rule is to be respected and followed, not questioned - or if you must do so, then the [meta](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/) site is a better place for that.